# Is there anything wrong with adding an HTML element as a direct child of document.documentElement?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, part of the functionality of which requires me to hide every html element at times with the exception of one div which I've created. (I hide everything and add the div to the current website in javascript) Because setting document.body.style.display = "none" will not allow any of the body's children to be seen, I need to add the child that I want to be seen somewhere else. (I also tried using style.visibility but for some reason that didn't hide certain HTML elements/backgrounds on certain pages.) My fix is to add the div to document.documentElement, outside of document.body. This fix actually works perfectly, but seems strange. Is there anything wrong with adding a new child to the  elements? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: A few answers have used the children of document.body, so I thought I should note that my code has to run at document_start, and though I wait for document.body to load before executing, I can't wait for all of its children to load. Hence I can't use/store the children of document.body. 
Also, I'm grateful for all the answers providing alternate solutions, they're quite useful. But out of curiosity, does anybody know if there's anything wrong with what I'm currently doing? Why is it working, if so?

Comment: Do you really need to keep the old `body` in the DOM? Maybe you could detach save `document.body` in a variable, replace it with a new body, and later put it back when you want to show everything again.

Comment: I've thought about that but my code runs in a content script at document start and even though I check that document.body exists I don't want to have to wait for and check that all its children have loaded. Thus, if I used this method, I worry that the body's children would not be loaded properly before I executed the code and thus when I restored the document.body the nodes that hadn't loaded would never load.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to add to documentElement because it's DOM , not HTML, and DOM specification doesn't care about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3C specification of [HTML document structure](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) says that it consists of the `<head>` and `<body>` elements, and the `<body>` contains the content that's intended to be rendered. Nothing is stated about elements outside these two elements.

If it seems to work it's probably just an accident of implementation -- for instances, many implementations are forgiving of things like malformed HTML.

Comment: If any of the elements were already hidden, you need to keep track of them so you don't show them when you revert.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to assume that the children of document.body have loaded at the time I have to run my code, so I can't use it, but thanks for the answer

Comment: I've replaced my answer with something that tries to address your main question.

Comment: DOM is not HTML so this answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new DIV to hold the children of the body, and hide that.

```
var saveDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
saveDiv.id = "saveDiv";
saveDiv.style.display = "none";
Array.from(document.body.children).forEach(el => saveDiv.appendChild(el));
document.body.appendChild(saveDiv);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to assume that the children of document.body have loaded at the time I have to run my code, so I can't use it, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**It's perfectly fine to append elements or text nodes directly to `document.documentElement`.**
DOM is not HTML, it has its own specification, which - being an **Object Model** - is naturally quite permissive:

1. `document.documentElement` is an Element [[spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#document-trees)]:

   > The document element of a document is the **element** whose parent is that document, if it exists, and null otherwise.
2. Elements are allowed to have these children [[spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-parent)]:

   > Zero or more nodes each of which is Element, Text, ProcessingInstruction, or Comment.

Answer (score -2):

A potential solution:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.innerHTML = `<div class="my-div"></div><div class="content">${body.innerHTML}</div>`;
```

Now you have the body content all snug alongside your div, both of which you can hide/show. As pointed out below, I completely spaced that this will destroy your listeners. If you want to preserve listeners, try the following:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const hideBody = () => {
  for (let el of [...body.children]) (fragment.append(el))
}
const showBody = () => {
  for (let el of [...fragment.children]) (body.append(el))
}
```

Attach the appropriate one to whatever your event is. This will preserve all your listeners. If you need any functionality, `DocumentFragment` has the `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods.

Another method is the modal method, where you just have a div that covers the whole page. Check out the [Bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), for example. If you initialize it with `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"` then it won't disappear by clicking outside or hitting <kbd>esc</kbd>. The element can be selected with `document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop')`. Set the opacity to 1 and the background to white or whatever aesthetic you're going for.

Comment: This will lose all properties of the body elements, including things like event listeners that are attached to them.

Comment: That's why you only attach listeners to the body ;)

I totally forgot that! Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to assume that the children of document.body have loaded at the time I have to run my code, so I can't use the first part, but thanks for the idea anyway. I'll look into the modal method though, that may work.